# Проблема компиляции в exe

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

Setup File:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"
setup(name='Vk bot GUI',
      version='0.1',
      executables=[Executable(script='vk_gui.py')])
```

Импорт библиотек в компилируемом python файле:

```
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import vk
from time import sleep
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from itertools import cycle
import fileinput
```

Ошибка:

```
import _tkinter # if this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
import error: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: если используете `r''`-строки, то [один слэш должен быть.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38656830/4279) У вас по этому путям dll присутствуют?

Comment: Если конечно еще актуально то похожий вопрос [cx_freeze не хочет собирать exe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765077/cx-freeze-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-exe/765080#765080)

Comment: @jfs, согласен, но вроде винда нейтрально к их удвоению относится?