# cx_freeze не хочет собирать exe

Tags: python, cx-freeze

`cx_freeze` не собирает мой `.py` файл в `.exe` и выдает ошибку:

```
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sold\Desktop\py\build.py", line 17, in <module>
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options}
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36    \lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36    \lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36    \lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36    \lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36    \lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36    \lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-            packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-        packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 616, in Freeze
        self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
      File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-         packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 340, in     _GetModuleFinder
    finder.IncludeModule(name)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 651, in IncludeModule
    namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 311, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 404, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 417, in _LoadModule
    namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 486, in _LoadPackage
    self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 464, in _LoadModule
    self._RunHook("load", module.name, module)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 537, in _RunHook
    method(self, *args)
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 615, in load_tkinter
    tclSourceDir = os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]
  File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py",     line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None 
 KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'
```

---

**Обновление вопроса**

Теперь возникает ошибка

```
File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36 \lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 36, in <module> 
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk 
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Comment: Я бы выкинул tcl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш `cx_freeze` не может найти `tcl_library` попробуйте вставить эти строки в начало вашего кода

```
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'
```

---

### UPDATE После обновления вопроса

После компиляции программы вам следует добавить в папку с программой 2 файла `.dll`, а именно

В папке `C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs` файлы `tcl86t.dll` и `tk86t.dll`

Похожий вопрос был на [Английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357202/8206722).

Сам код программы:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "includes": ["tkinter"]}
sys.argv.append("build")
filename = "main.py"
base = "Win32GUI"
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
setup(
    name="Unick Locker",
    version="1.0",
    description="description",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable(filename, base=base)])
```

Comment: Спасибо, .exe он собрал, но тут другая проблема всплыла:
      File "C:\Users\Sold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36    \lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
        import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

Comment: @Sold обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, с наступающим!